# TypeScript Iterate over object and create a type from the values

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

Given I have an object like this:

```js
const props = [
    { name: 'car', list: { brand: 'audi', model: 's4' }
    { name: 'motorcycle', list: { type: 'ktm', color: 'orange' }
] as constant;
```

I want to create a type that represents something like this:

```js
type Props = {
    car?: 'brand' | 'model',
    motorcycle?: 'type' | 'color'
};
```

The closest I got was something like this:

```js
type Props = Partial<Record<typeof props[number]['name'], typeof props[number]['list']>
```

But returns something like this:

```js
type Props = {
    car?: { brand: 'audi', model: 's4' } | { type: 'ktm' | color: 'orange' } | undefined,
    motorcycle?: { brand: 'audi', model: 's4' } | { type: 'ktm' | color: 'orange' } | undefined
}
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *key remapping* that was introduced in TypeScript 4.1 ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types)) to achieve this:

```
type IndexKeys<T> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof []>
type ListProp = { name: string, list: object }
type GetName<P> = P extends ListProp ? P['name'] : never
type GetListKeys<P> = P extends ListProp ? keyof P['list'] : never

type PropsFromList<PropList extends ReadonlyArray<ListProp>> = {
  [i in IndexKeys<PropList> as GetName<PropList[i]>]?: GetListKeys<PropList[i]>
}

type Props = PropsFromList<typeof props>
// Inferred type:
// Props: {
//     car?: "brand" | "model" | undefined;
//     motorcycle?: "type" | "color" | undefined;
// }
```

Note that just like when using `Partial`, the optional property types get an extra but harmless `| undefined`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHCMC8MDaBYAUDAmAbxjAEMBbAUwC4YByYMhegGhgBsBLaOkgIwRkwAEzr0yAVxFc2MCiBFUO4iABZ6MAL5bWeQsVKVaDBVBAJgAT2Acqc7r0NQrcE-QDWUCnNAcL4hbCAOb22lp4ALowZKigkFAA3Hh4Lm4wAJKiVAAeANJUVhAAPAAqAHzoMACiObbSVMUehSAAZjCl7M1WbViR5amuVDAAMjxQAApIcFUk5NR00AhcYMHsjlB0IPwAVlTAsBG4acMA4lRQAHLGxROVGBMwuVBUoqhj0FPIMAD8MBOYejzezROhgKgANyoCEG6XOUA+UAKRVu93+TxyLzeo3GXxmf26vQB9A29FBpEh0JSxyG-2mEAAYkgKIjbtNERisSJUAAlKhkETgDhWACCCCEVmKiLx5TRRH0WC4MBWmWy+UKJTxiMqsRg8Ou1DZyERmC4-UiPzo8MRyM17PGpv6eCOsOGeNQD3pTJALPGxROvUQyAgA1wAHow6rWtCEFQRDATjQ8BG6cG+MnIwYmAhLTAAESCYQiPMwAA++YUSg4JfLkmyrRWceS4czhDMFmstioubzJxr+b8Fn7daUDfBImbKaOQA)

Comment: Glad to help! The second thing seems be possible, but to keep this question clear, I'd suggest creating a new question for it.